# Onvif get profiles

Tags: c#, onvif

today i'm using a VDX camera and i'd like to control it using Onvif protocol.
In my program I need to do a "GetProfiles" request.

With other cameras (Bosh, Lumens, Axis, ec...) my method works properly but with VDX I have a lot of problems.
In particular if I using the follow snippet (using port 80), the server throws an exception (error 414 URI too large):

```
    var httpTransport = new HttpTransportBindingElement
{
    AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.Digest
};

var binding = new CustomBinding(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement
    (MessageVersion.None, Encoding.Default), httpTransport);

    var builder = new UriBuilder("http", "10.0.34.32", 80, "/onvif/media_service");
    var mediaAddress = builder.Uri;

    var mediaClient = new MediaClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(mediaAddress));
    mediaClient.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential.UserName = username;
    mediaClient.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential.Password = password;

    var getProfilesResponse = await mediaClient.GetProfilesAsync();
    var profiles = getProfilesResponse.Profiles;
}
```

If I change port number with 81 the server responds without error but profiles is null (there are 2 profiles actually).

Accessing with the camera webpage I found this ports numbers:
[image]

Using Onvif Device Manager it works properly... someone can tell me my what I wrong?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

How did you choose to connect to the media service on port `80` with relative URI `/onvif/media_service`? Probably you are not using the correct one (and hard-coding them in code is bad, since newer versions of the firmware may change it).

You should invoke `GetServices` from the [device management service](https://www.onvif.org/specs/core/ONVIF-Core-Specification.pdf) and use the correct URI to access the desired service.